# How to add 3 attempts in a login page

Tags: php, html, security, authentication

hello everyone i just wanna ask on how to add three attempts in my login page here is the code

```
<?php  
include 'connect.php';
?>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
session_start();
include("config_DB.php"); //including config.php in our file
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username'])); 
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(md5($_POST['password']))); 
$user_type= $_GET['user_type'];



$match = "select * from $table where username = '".$username."' and password = '".sha1($password)."';"; 

$qry = mysql_query($match);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry); 


if($num_rows >= 1){
    $_SESSION['user']= $_POST["username"];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['empName'];
    $_SESSION['position'] = $row['empPosition'];
    $_SESSION['user_type'] = $row['user_type'];
        header("location:index.php/index_controller/home"); 
} else { 
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username'])); 
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['password'])); 

    include("config_DB.php"); //including config.php in our file
    $match = "select * from $table where username = '".$username."' and password = '".sha1($password)."';"; 
    $qry = mysql_query($match);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry);
    $attemps =0;
    if($num_rows <= 0){

         echo

        "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
        "window.alert('Invalid username/password!');".
        'window.location.href="index.php";'.
        "</script>";

    exit;   
    }
    $_SESSION['user']= $_POST["username"];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['empName'];
    $_SESSION['position'] = $row['empPosition'];
    $_SESSION['user_type'] = $row['user_type'];
    header("location:index.php/index_controller/home");
} 
}else{
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">   
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>City Planning and Development Office--Login</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/login-style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/less/icons.less"/>

    <!-- Load JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Load Metro JavaScript -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/load-metro.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/metro.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/metro-calendar.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/metro-datepicker.js"></script>

    <!-- Load Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/validate.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/condition.js"></script>

    <!-- Login parallax -->
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        background:#000;
    }
    input.info{
        color:#000 !important;
    }
    .vertical-offset-100{
    padding-top:100px;
    }
    .login{
        background:#ed1c24;
        color:#fff;
    }
     body{
    background: url(img/back.png);
    background-color: #444;
    background: url(/cpdo_ci/assets/images/pinlayer2.png),url(/cpdo_ci/assets/images/pinlayer1.png),url(/cpdo_ci/assets/images/back.png);    
    }
    .vertical-offset-100{
    padding-top:100px;
    }
    </style>    

</head>
<body>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/TweenLite.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" >
    <div class="row vertical-offset-100">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row-fluid user-row">
                        <center><img src="/cpdo_ci/assets/images/malolos.png" height="200" width="200" alt="CPDO"></center>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="login" class="form-signin"  role="form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control info" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" required type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control info" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" required type="password" value="">
                        </div>
                            <label>
                                <div style="  font-size:90%" >

                                </div>
                            </label>
                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
                    </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
     TweenLite.to($('body'), 
        .5, 
        { css: 
            {
                backgroundPosition: ""+ parseInt(event.pageX/8) + "px "+parseInt(event.pageY/'12')+"px, "+parseInt(event.pageX/'15')+"px "+parseInt(event.pageY/'15')+"px, "+parseInt(event.pageX/'30')+"px "+parseInt(event.pageY/'30')+"px"
            }
        });
  });
});
</script>
</body>
<?php
}
?>

</html>

</html>
```

Comment: `if ($failed && $_SESSION['attempts']++ < 3) { allow more attempts }`

Comment: Do you want to just have 3 attempts per session, or do you maybe want to lock their accouunt? Somebody could just reopen their browser after 3 attempts and try again. I might suggest the latter, by adding a Boolean IsLocked column to your user table. At that point you might require them to enter their email, and then send them a link with how to reset their password.

Comment: I would recommend adding the 'isLocked' to the user table as well.  In addition I set an expiration for when the lock will expire.  That way you can do things like 'If 5 bad attempts, lock for 30 minutes'  then the REAL user can still login later without resetting his password if someone tried to access his account.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to the back-end which receives the login parameters.

```
if($_POST["password"]) !== $password_stored_in_db) {
if($attempts == 3) {
header('Location: login.php?max_attempt=exceeded');
}
} else if (isset($attempts)) {
$attempts = ++ $attempts;
} else {
$attempts = 0;
}

header('Location: login.php?attempt=' . $attempts);
```

Also add this to login.php to determine if user has exceeded max attempts:

Make sure that login.php is set to check for max_attempt=exceeded by adding:

```
if(isset($_GET["max_attempt"])) {
if($_GET["max_attempt"] == "exceeded") {
// Error message
// Use $_SESSION to record the time and to stop user from trying again for a while because if you use cookies, it maybe overridden or re-set.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should store the information of attempts on the DB, but some quick hack by storing the data on the session would be

```
<?php  
include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
    session_start();
    include("config_DB.php"); //including config.php in our file
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username'])); 
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(md5($_POST['password']))); 
    $user_type= $_GET['user_type'];

    $match = "select * from $table where username = '".$username."' and password = '".sha1($password)."';"; 

    $qry = mysql_query($match);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry); 

    if($num_rows >= 1){
        $_SESSION['attemps'] = 0;
        $_SESSION['user']= $_POST["username"];
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['empName'];
        $_SESSION['position'] = $row['empPosition'];
        $_SESSION['user_type'] = $row['user_type'];
        header("your_home_page"); 
    } else { 
        $_SESSION['attemps'] ||= 0;
        $_SESSION['attemps'] += 1;
        if ($_SESSION['attemps'] > 3) {
            header("location:/access_denied.php");
        }               
        $display_warning = true;    
    } 
}else{
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">   
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>City Planning and Development Office--Login</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/login-style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/less/icons.less"/>

        <!-- Load JavaScript Libraries -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Load Metro JavaScript -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/load-metro.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/metro.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/metro-calendar.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/metro-datepicker.js"></script>

        <!-- Load Bootstrap JavaScript -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/validate.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/condition.js"></script>

        <!-- Login parallax -->
        <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background:#000;
        }
        input.info{
            color:#000 !important;
        }
        .vertical-offset-100{
            padding-top:100px;
        }
        .login{
            background:#ed1c24;
            color:#fff;
        }
        body{
            background: url(img/back.png);
            background-color: #444;
            background: url(/cpdo_ci/assets/images/pinlayer2.png),url(/cpdo_ci/assets/images/pinlayer1.png),url(/cpdo_ci/assets/images/back.png);    
        }
        .vertical-offset-100{
            padding-top:100px;
        }
        </style>    

    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/TweenLite.min.js"></script>

        <div class="container" >
            <div class="row vertical-offset-100">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row-fluid user-row">
                                <center><img src="/cpdo_ci/assets/images/malolos.png" height="200" width="200" alt="CPDO"></center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="login" class="form-signin"  role="form">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control info" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" required type="text">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control info" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" required type="password" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <label>
                                        <div style="  font-size:90%" >

                                        </div>
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            <?php if defined($display_warning) : ?>
            window.alert('Invalid username/password!');
            <?php endif; ?>         

            $(document).mousemove(function(e){
                TweenLite.to($('body'), 
                .5, 
                { css: 
                    {
                        backgroundPosition: ""+ parseInt(event.pageX/8) + "px "+parseInt(event.pageY/'12')+"px, "+parseInt(event.pageX/'15')+"px "+parseInt(event.pageY/'15')+"px, "+parseInt(event.pageX/'30')+"px "+parseInt(event.pageY/'30')+"px"
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

</html>
```